# TradingView MovingAverage Crossover Strategy

Tags: tradingview-api

The MovingAverage Crossover Strategy (i.e. 5MA/20MA) looks good in performance but sometimes the strategy loses the opportunity to gain profit because the next crossover is a bit late.
My idea is to place a stop order to secure the profit despite the nest crossover and wish to write a Pine code to realize it.

Does anybody help me to show the Pine code when the position gains some unrealized profit after a certain crossover/crossunder in the MovingAvg2Line Cross Strategy, the profit saving order（stop order) will be placed at a certain level (i.e. 100 pts) above or below the entry price.

Answer (score 0):

Add [strategy.exit](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy.exit)

and use `profit` in **ticks** (no pts)

Somelike this:

```
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(id = 'TP', from_entry = 'MA2CrossLE', profit = 100)
```

Comment: Gu5tavo71
Thank you very much. It works !!